# window.onload DOM loading in popup, browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have HTML popup window and i want add text after opening window with spec. function:

```
var win = window.open('private.php', data.sender_id , 'width=300,height=400');                      
win.window.onload = function() {
         //function for add text
         //chrome and firefox fire, IE and Opera not
};
```

This work perfectly with Chrome and Firefox, but Opera and IE9 won't working. Please tell me 
best way to do that with IE and Opera.
I try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //function for add text
});
```

but same thing.

I found solution, but i wont know is there better solution then setTimeout???

Instead onload event i use:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 //add text
},200);
```

Comment: why not add this `onload`/`onready` in private.php?

Comment: Because i need in index.php add text and call some other function.

Comment: This is small part of code, but onload event make problem. FF/Chrome works like i said.

Comment: Because i need in index.php detect event when popup is loaded, and then use some other functions.

Comment: you could use a callback defined in index.php and call it from private.php using the `window.parent.callback(...)`

Comment: I need add text in private.php only from index.php when private.php is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
function callback() {
   // ...
   return xxx;
}
```

private.php

```
 $(document).read(function() {
     var text_to_insert = window.opener.callback();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (tested in chrome, FF, IE but don't know about opera)

```
var win = window.open('private.php', data.sender_id , 'width=300,height=400');
win[win.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent']((win.attachEvent ? 'on' : '') + 'load', myFunction, false);
function myFunction(){
    win.focus();
    win.document.write('loaded...');
}​
```

You may also try [DOMContentLoaded](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded) event, if it works.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyP3b/3/).